# I want to serve PDF files stored in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to serve PDF files stored in Google Cloud Storage.
I tried:

```
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import images
bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + filename)
url = images.get_serving_url(bkey)
```

Error:

```
get_serving_url_hook\n raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)\n', 'TransformationError\n']
```

Comment: Is it App Engine python 2 that you use?

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the PDF file as if it wan image. You cannot use the 'images' api with a pdf file. There are several ways of storing and serving static files, which you can find from this link [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files